# May I delete Compiz Session files

Tags: compiz

Brand new poster.  Been using Ubuntu for several years, but I am not a 'power-user'.  I'm running 14.10 on a HP Pavilion Laptop. (32bit version).

My question is that while doing a back up the other day, I noticed that there were a bazillion 'session' files being backed up from the hidden directory /home/.compiz/session.
These are small files, but I was wondering if I could delete them since they go back to 2012 when I got the laptop.  Is it safe to just wipe out everything but the last couple of files?  (I noticed that some days have multiple session files, which must come every time I start the computer).

Thanks in advance.  AND...if you know of any other stuff like this that needs to be cleaned off, let me know.  I'm rather O.C.D. about my hard drive.

TKS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+question/211844) that also has this to say: If you want to do this at boot time edit `/etc/rc.local` and add a `rm /home/{username}/.compiz/session/*` where {username} needs to change to your username. The source claims it works with no problems at all.

A little bit more safe is to delete files older than X hours:

```
 find ~/.compiz/session/ -name {filenames} -type f -mmin +{X*60) -delete
```

- change {filenames} to something addressing those files you want gone; use a wildcard if needed.
- change {X*60} to how old the files need to be in minutes.

By the way: I have NO .compiz and no .compiz/session in my system. It might have been removed during any of the newer Ubuntu versions (`.config/compiz-1` does exist on my system).

Comment: The sample code provided doesn't work.

Comment: @DustWolf examples from 3 years ago can not be applied to current versions. Even so: those sessions files back in 2014 where a BUG so it is more than likely this was fixed and can no longer work. (nevertheless the command itself is correct and valid).